# Generics Problem - Cannot compile code, possibly due to type erasure

Tags: java, compiler-errors, type-erasure

I have some code similar to this:

```
public class A<E> {
     protected E value;

     public E getValue() { 
         return value;
     }

     public void setValue(E value) {
         this.value = value;
     }
}
```

Then I have a class to extend this class, called B

```
public class B extends A<Boolean> {
     // B has some other code, but doesn't edit the set/get methods
}
```

Then I compile these two classes to A.class, B.class and they're JARed.

Then I have the following code:

```
public class C {
// ... snip
     B var = new B();
     var.setValue(true);
     if(var.getValue()) {
         // etc
     }
// ... snip
}
```

Attempting to compile this results in an error telling me that var.getValue returns as an Object. I KNOW it's a boolean, and when I include that C with the A/B java files and compile all at once, it works fine.

But when I compile A/B separately to C I get the issue that it believes var.getValue is an Object.

I've been reading about generics and Type Erasure, but I couldn't figure a way to solve it.

I'm trying to build A/B into a package that classes like C use, but if I have to cast all getValues then there is no point in generics.

Where am I going wrong?

(The actual code is in [this github repo](https://github.com/Clintonxa/ModOptionsAPI/tree/master/files/modoptionsapi) and the offending classes that are A and B are ModOption/ModBooleanOption. I don't have the C code in there, but it's obvious)

Edit: I'm using JavaSE6 compiling and obfuscating. The weird thing is that if I compile regularly and then try this example is also works fine. I'm beginning to suspect the obfuscator.

This problem is solved; I tested further and discovered that the obfuscator is breaking the generics, I have no idea how and don't care why. I'll be contacting the maintainers of it.

Comment: What SDK are you using? Your example compiles just fine for me (separately or together) using jdk1.6.0_25.

Comment: @jkraybill Java SDK 6. In the production version the code is run up against an obfuscator (not my choice) and that's the only difference.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since the problem is the obfuscator, can you share which one you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this *only* by setting my compiler to `javac -source 1.4` while compiling C. If you're using an IDE, check the project that contains C to make sure your Java VM and source support is at 1.5 or above.

Comment: Java SDK 6. In the production version the code is run up against an obfuscator (not my choice) and that's the only difference.

Comment: It turns out the obfuscator was ancient. The owners won't upgrade. It turns out I have to give up with it and just use no generics.